# Initializing the constants in an enum with values from a property file

Tags: java

I have an enum in one of my project and I have used my constants here. However, I want to initialize these constants with values from a property file. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "here"?

Comment: Could you just read the properties file and get the data assigned by each enum value name?

Answer (score 2):

Enums are created at compile time, so no chance to change them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of enum values, you could use [Enum with values](http://snipplr.com/view/42422/the-planet-enum-example/) to insert values from property file.

In other case, it is not possible to populate enum at execution time, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409071/is-it-possible-to-create-java-enums-based-on-input-file)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have compiler with me, but if I understand correctly what you want is something similar to this:

```
public enum YourEnum{
    VALUE("default");

    private String name;

    YourEnum(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    static{
        //below line you must implement your own property reading style from your file
        YourEnum.VALUE.name = FileUtil.readFromYourFile("propertyName");
    }
}
```

Hope, it helps, I'll have a look and correct if there are any compile errors when I get the chance to compile.